# Does Boost R-tree support hierarchy traverse?

Tags: c++, boost, r-tree

It seems that the [R-tree](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/geometry/doc/html/geometry/reference/spatial_indexes/boost__geometry__index__rtree.html) in Boost does not support hierarchy traverse.

To be specific, I want to get `root` node of the R-tree, and then get the children of the node.

Does Boost R-tree support hierarchy traverse ?

Comment: Indeed doesn't seem to be there. I think the order in which `begin()..end()` traverses depends on the chosen parameters too http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/geometry/doc/html/geometry/reference/spatial_indexes/parameters.html

Comment: @sehe `begin() ... end()` returns the iterator of the leaf node. I would like the internal node.

Comment: I never disputed that. Hence I started out with "doesn't seem to be there"

Answer (score 1):

In case this was XY problem. What would you like to do exactly?

Regarding your question. User-defined tree traversal is not officially supported. However if you're not affraid to dig in the internals then you could write your own node visitor, like this one:

https://github.com/boostorg/geometry/blob/develop/include/boost/geometry/index/detail/rtree/utilities/print.hpp#L133

And use it like this:

https://github.com/boostorg/geometry/blob/develop/include/boost/geometry/index/detail/rtree/utilities/print.hpp#L200