# Find children of given R-Tree node

Tags: c++, boost, boost-geometry, r-tree

I need to know the hierarchy of my rtree. In particular, given a `Node`, I'd like to know its children.

I've seen that in this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37337758/does-boost-r-tree-support-hierarchy-traverse) there's a link to the following line in GitHub sources:

https://github.com/boostorg/geometry/blob/f92671b933e585ecba3c1b02c830f6e90e813da9/include/boost/geometry/index/detail/rtree/utilities/print.hpp#L160

where `n` is an `InternalNode`. From my understanding, `it->first` is the bounding box, while `it->second` is the indexable. However, I don't see how one can query the children of a specific node. Is there any way to find them?

I am completely stuck at the moment

Comment: the code you are linking to there is recursively applying the visitor on the range defined by the iterators rtree::elements(n)::begin() to rtree::elements(n)::end(), so I assume those are the children of n. But why do you need to traverse the internal representation of the r-tree?

Comment: The reason is the following: suppose I am in level 1 of the rtree. For each node of the level, I need to know the children (that are leafs in this case). If `it` is an iterator to a child, how can I ask information about it? To be more precise: if my rtree is constructed with pairs of points and integers, how can I known the integers associated to the the leafs? I'm trying to find that but I can't find any example. @jwezorek

Comment: But what are you trying to do that you can do with the `query` interface? Why do you care about the tree's structure if you can do range searches etc. over it.

Comment: Unfortunately, I really need to known the hierarchy, and queries are not really helping with that. All I need to know now is how to get from `it` its `Value`, where with `Value` I mean the pair describing each Node. Do you know how to get that? @jwezorek